# Two column layout not working in bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

So i have a technical interview I need to do for a job. I'm not sure why this code isn't working. I'm trying to create a two column layout in bootstrap 4. Seems i have all the divs in place and the two column layout isn't showing up. I loaded bootstrap 4 with a CDN in wordpress and create a custom homepage. Where it says sidebarhome.php that is what i am looking to have on the right column layout, and the blog posts on the left.

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
 * @package home
 */

get_header();
?>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <main id="primary" class="site-main">
                <h1>.COM</h1>
                <h2>School Life</h2>
                <?php
                if ( have_posts() ) :

                    if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) :
                        ?>
                        <header>
                            <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
                        </header>
                        <?php
                    endif;

                    /* Start the Loop */
                    while ( have_posts() ) :
                        the_post();

                        /*
                         * Include the Post-Type-specific template for the content.
                         * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                         * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Type name) and that will be used instead.
                         */
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

                    endwhile;

                    the_posts_navigation();

                else :

                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

                endif;
                ?>

            </main><!-- #main -->
</div>
</div>


<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php include 'sidebarhome.php';?>
        </div>
</div>


</div><!--End Container-->

<?php
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you.

Currently, you have taken different rows for different columns.

If you want to add ***sidebarhome.php*** on the right column layout, and the ***blog-posts*** on the left column layout, you are supposed to put both the columns `col-md-6` in one `row`.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    All blog posts (the_post();)
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    Sidebar Home content (sidebarhome.php)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I did last night and it worked! Thank you very much for your answer, it worked perfectly.